# Displaying TabularData in Windows Forms C Sharp

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently In Windows Form C Sharp we have data grid View for displaying tabular.
Now supposing you wanted to create a summary of your data as below. In a Table.
Think of a HTML Table summary as a example. But in this case you are doing it on a Windows Form Interface.

| Name | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 2500 |
| Name 2 | 4500 |
| Total | 6500 |

Then display this in windows form. Currently I don't know of any control in Windows Form that can achieve this.

Comment: I've not used it, but you can check out DevExpress GridControl 
 https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114624/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/getting-started/walkthroughs/summaries/tutorial-total-summaries

Comment: Another DataGridView is not enough? Too much? What about a ListView? It supports columns with headers. -- It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: With DataGridView you cannot have the totals on the last row. From its design it does not look like DGView was made to display summary of data in a table

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Yes that seems like the solution I need but now without having to purchase it. How come Microsoft have overlooked the issue entirely.

Comment: Since this is a *summary* (the way you described it), thus just to *display* values, the DataGridView doesn't need to be bound to a datasource. You can add rows manually. The same using a ListView.